# TIFF files having black background in Image Library

Tags: library, image-upload

I have uploaded a TIFF file in an image library which supposed to be transparent and will appear to have a white background. But in turned out to have a black background. And when I check the code through inspect element, the image is saved as jpg. But when downloaded it is a Tiff file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is there a fix on this?

Comment: This section is for answers (you will be able to post comments with some more reputation), but shortly, no there is no easy fix. The only fix I can think of is creating your own "preview" view that uses the original (heavy) image instead of the created previews

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint creates some preview images (2 I think) for every picture uploaded to a library.

The code used to create those images unfortunately creates `.jpg` which do not support transparent backgrounds which then turn black.

The "real" images is still keeping its original format and hence will still be transparent

Comment: So how do you solve it?

Comment: See my comment on the original question. Or if in 2013 use image renditions for creating your own view listing

Comment: I read your comment - you said there is no "easy" fix.  How can you add your own "preview" thumbnail?